# Creating dataframe based on first record per day in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am looking at exercise data and trying to analyze workouts that follow a **completed workout.**

Currently I'm grouping by user and date to get the first instance of each workout per user, per day:
`df.groupby(['user_id', 'start_date']).nth(0)`

Now I want to use this to get all the instances where `df['workout_complete'] = True`.

Then with that selection, I want to **filter the overall df** for all records per user, per day where the nth(0) record was True. This should include the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. records on each day where the first was True.

Comment: Fitler the dataframe then groupby? `df[df['workout_complete'] == True].groupby(['user_id', 'start_date']).nth(0)`

Comment: That gets the first complete workout each day, but I want the data where the first workout is complete and then all the records for each user/day where the first ```df'workout_complete' = True```

So the 2nd, 3rd, 4th workouts on those given days as well.